# TFS global list not available in integrated in field

Tags: tfsbuild, workitem

we customized our CMMI Process Template that we use with TFS 2010.

To avoid flooding of the Builds - [Team Project] list in the Global List we removed the event subscription from TFS that fills this list with every build (BISSUBSCRIBE).
We fill this list only when a builds quality is set to "Ready for initial test" with a TFS plugin that watches the change of build qualities (found [here](http://intovsts.net/category/team-build/)). The builds are listet in global list under "Builds - [TeamProjectName]".
The global list looks fine but the items are not available in the work items (Bugs field "Integration Build" etc.).

Our Bug Work Item Type field "Integration Build" is defined like this:

```
<FieldDefinition name="Integration Build" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES>
        <LISTITEM value="&lt;None&gt;" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
    <HELPTEXT>The build in which the bug was fixed</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
```

The Bug Work Item Type Layout for the control to edit Integration Build is defined like this:

```
<Control FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Build.IntegrationBuild" Type="FieldControl" Label="&amp;Integrated In:" LabelPosition="Left" />
```

Seems like we cutted the magic that pulls items from the Global List into the control.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
      <GLOBALLIST name="Builds - XXXXX" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
```

I think this is what you need based on our template, where XXXXX is the Project Name. Ours is added after your already existing Suggested Values so we have two of those nodes